# Reading or Converting Midi Files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, wav, midi

I'm trying to read a midi file in MatLab but I was unable to find a practical way to do it. Is there any suggestions on how to read a midi file just like reading a wav file via wavread()? Or is there any built-in midi-to-wav conversion function in matlab or can you suggest any tool for this conversion in order to create a matlab readable wav file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at the MATLAB MIDI synth library by Ken Schutte.. http://www.kenschutte.com/midi

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the MIDI data itself (rather than 
audio data generated from the MIDI), then the Midi Toolbox 
by Petri Toiviainen and Tuomas Eerola is a good choice:
https://www.jyu.fi/hum/laitokset/musiikki/en/research/coe/materials/miditoolbox 
There are improved midi read and write functions that were contributed 
by Christine Smit, which are available here:
http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~csmit/matlab_midi.html